# Links not working in template?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using a Bootstrap template and just noticed that the links don't work properly for certain pages when they are accessed in mobile resolution.

Example here: https://www.cadsys.net/si_members.html

Firebug is not showing any issues.

Anyone? Thanks, Bob

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Turns out I had duplicate JQuery links in the pages. Solved.